# Out of memory; SQLite Database crashed

Tags: android, sqlite, out-of-memory, android-sqlite

When I open a Fragment, and I start filling a AridAdapter, that Adapter takes the  data from a SQLite Database.
But something goes wrong, and I get an `out of memory` exception and the app stops.

Some Code:

```
Database database;

String[] Description;

String[] Title;
int[] Minute;
 int[] Hour;
int[] Day;
int[] Month;
int[] Year;
 int mId;
public Integer[] mThumbIds;

private Context mContext;
private int ACTIVE;


public void DataPrepear(int ACTIVE){
    database = new Database(mContext);
    mId = database.getLastIdOD();
    database.close();
    for(int i=1;i==mId;i++){
        database = new Database(mContext);
    OneDayTD notification = database.getOneDay(i);
        if(notification.getActive()==ACTIVE) {
            Title[i - 1] = notification.getTitle();
            Description[i-1] = notification.getContent();
            Minute[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getMinuteInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Hour[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getHourInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Day[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getDayInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Month[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getMonthInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Year[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getYearInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            mThumbIds[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(notification.getIcon());
            database.close();
        }

   }

}
```

Log:

```
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2154)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:178)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.ui.fragments.OneDayTasks.onCreateView(OneDayTasks.java:68)
03-12 07:34:51.908 24239-24239/com.universe.time.officereminder E/art:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2114)
```

Comment: post your log and outof memory message what you caught

Comment: Don't post such huge log. Just post the lines where you have got the error. No one will read such lengthy log.

Comment: You clearly have a loop either calling itself or not incrementing properly. It's not this code, though the for loop conditions seem wrong also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you see in the log is in your `OneDayTasks` fragment.

In its `onCreateView()` you inflate a layout that seems to have a `<fragment>` tag for `OneDayTasks` which results in `onCreateView()` be called again and so on. Infinite recursion that gets terminated when you run out of stack memory.

To fix it, remove the `fragment` self-reference from the layout you inflate in your fragment code.